# why does zebra printer output use ^GFA ?

Tags: zebra-printers

I designed a label in a Zebra Label Designer and outputed the zpl code to a file.  All my text is encoded in a ^GFA command which is not useable to me because I want to be able to replace text in the label progromatically. How do I design my labels so that the text is not encoded in the program code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use printer-resident fonts when you add a text field in ZebraDesigner. The printer-resident font names listed in the dropdown box of ZebraDesigner typically start with the word Zebra.

Comment: If you want to use a different font you will need to use the font and graphic downloader that comes with Designer. https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO6674&actp=RSS